# MSDeploy Package File Filtering

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

In my MSBuild Script I am using MSDeploy to package and deploy my ASP.NET MVC website.

```
<Exec Command='  "@(MsDeploy)" -verb:sync -source:iisApp="$(Source)" -dest:package="$(Destination)" '/>
```

The issue is that my  *.less files are not added to the deployment package.

Are there parameters or a configuration, I can set so these files are added to the deployment package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the Web Publishing Pipeline will pick up only files needed for deployment (unless you specify differently in the Package/Publish Web tab), which means the build action needs to be Content for those files.  (You can see the Build Action property in the Properties window in Visual Studio when you select a file in Solution Explorer.)  See the Deployment FAQ on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#why_dont_all_files_get_deployed

Comment: Set the Build Action to Content and Copy to Output Directory Always.